# SwiftUI mac remove close item from files menu

Tags: macos, swiftui, menu

In the file menu in every mac app, you will have this close menu item:

[image: close menu item]

How can I remove it in swiftUI?

Or is there a `CommandGroupPlacement` corresponding to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CommandGroupPlacement.saveItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/commandgroupplacement/saveitem):

> Includes the following by default on macOS:
>
> - Close
> - Save
> - Save As/Duplicate
> - Revert to Saved

Comment: And how can hide only that item?

Comment: You'll need to recreate the other items yourself.

Comment: And what if I want to hide the whole "Edit" item?