# Create a window that cannot be closed by CMD+W

Tags: macos, swiftui, appkit

Is it possible to create a main window that cannot be closed by the shortcut Command + W ?
The view concerned is a toolbar: it is not resizable and has no close button.

Here's the content of the AppDelegate (swift) :

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ProductiveBoxApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Toolbar()
                .background(TitleBarHiddenWindow())
        }
        .windowStyle(HiddenTitleBarWindowStyle())
        .windowResizability(.contentSize)
    }
}

struct TitleBarHiddenWindow: NSViewRepresentable {
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        let view = NSView()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let window = view.window {
                window.titleVisibility = .hidden
                window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
                window.standardWindowButton(.closeButton)?.isHidden = true
                window.standardWindowButton(.zoomButton)?.isHidden = true
                window.standardWindowButton(.miniaturizeButton)?.isHidden = true
                window.level = .floating
            }
        }
        return view
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {}
}
```

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74954016/swiftui-mac-remove-close-item-from-files-menu?rq=1

Comment: more examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75990536/remove-close-cmdw-menu-bar-button-not-working-swiftui

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI mac remove close item from files menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74954016/swiftui-mac-remove-close-item-from-files-menu)